# How to check Lat Long is within particular City?

Tags: java, android, location

I want to check whether my lat long belongs to particular city or not.
I am receiving my lat and long from `placeAutoComplete.IntentBuilder`

```
try {
  Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
    .setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
      new LatLng(Double.valueOf(18.5204), Double.valueOf(73.8567)),
      new LatLng(Double.valueOf(18.5204), Double.valueOf(73.8567))))
    .build(CheckOut.this);

  startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
  // TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
  // TODO: Handle the error.
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
      Log.i("place", "Place: " + place.getLatLng());
      LatLng placeLatLong= place.getLatLng();
      user_lat = String.valueOf(placeLatLong.latitude);
      user_long = String.valueOf(placeLatLong.longitude);
      tvAddress2Popup.setText(String.valueOf(place.getName()));
    } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
      Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
      // TODO: Handle the error.
      Log.i("", status.getStatusMessage());
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
      // The user canceled the operation.
    }
  }
}
```

please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try below google api,you will get all the particular place details

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=xxxx&key=APi_key

Answer (score 0):

You can find out city name and detail using Reverse Geocoding http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding.

Or you can use google apis to find out all detail using Latitude and Longitude
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=26.8432779,77.8027763&sensor=true

After checked this you may find out solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); 
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postal_Code = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String Name = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check like this

```
String latitudeStr = String.valueOf(address.getLatitude());
                latitudeStr = latitudeStr.substring ( latitudeStr.indexOf ( "." ) );

                String longitudeStr = String.valueOf(address.getLongitude());
                longitudeStr = longitudeStr.substring ( longitudeStr.indexOf ( "." ) );


                if(latitudeStr.length()>=8) {

                //this is city  
                }
```

by this you can get the city lat long ..